# Error while trying to import an Excel file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import-from-excel

I use SQL Server 2022 Express, and SQL Server Management Studio.

I'm trying to import an Excel file into a database I created. I click on its name with the right button => task => import data. Then a window opened for me for a second and closed.

I tried to click on SQL Server "Import and Export", and I get the error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (DTSWizard)

When I click on import flag, it works but it doesn't suit me

Answer (score 1):

use `Xls` instead of `Xlsx`,save your excel file as `Excel 1997-2003`, it might solve the issue.